# How to remove an impulse with numerous touches (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

I made control for the game when you touch, the character flies to the left side, when touching the second time the character flies to the right side , but when the character is in flight and I touch many times, the character throws in different directions, and he flies  up,  How to fix it

I want the impulse not to work when the player is in flight

```
enum BodyType: UInt32 {
     case playerr = 1
     case walll = 2
}

var direction: Direction?
var isInFlight = true    






override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent? {

 if isInFlight == true {
        return

    } else  {


    player?.removeAllActions()

    switch direction  {
    case .left:
        player?.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: 700, y: 0, duration: 1))
        player?.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 700, dy: 500))

        direction = .right
    case .right:
        player?.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: -700, y: 0, duration: 1))
        player?.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -700, dy: 
 500))

        direction     

 }

 }



 func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    let secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if ( firstBody.categoryBitMask == BodyType.playerr.rawValue && secondBody.categoryBitMask == BodyType.walll.rawValue) {

        print("Add")
        isInFlight = false 

    }

}


func didEnd(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    let secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == BodyType.playerr.rawValue && secondBody.categoryBitMask == BodyType.walll.rawValue) {
        print("End")
        isInFlight = true 

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) don't ever use images to share code, SO is designed for code to be formatted so people can use it. 2) You are doing both actions and physics, which is really screwing both engines.  Pick one or the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish with your app but this is what I mean by setting the `isInFlight` bool to true/false using `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`. Very simple concept, but they way you implement it in your app logic is up to you.

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        isInFlight = false
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        isInFlight = true
    }
```

Comment: I added an impulse to the player, but this did not solve the problem

Comment: In that case, I think the problem must be elsewhere in your code. If you have a Github account, maybe you can replicate the issue in a sample project and share the full code on Github. That would make it easier for people to find the problem.

Comment: I updated this question. look up, it may be more clear what I want to do

Comment: If you don't want the impulse to work when the player is in flight, set a bool like `isInFlight = true` when the player is in flight. Then check for the bool in the `touchesBegan` method and don't add the impulse if the bool is true, i.e. `if isInFlight == true { return } else { // add the impulse like you are doing }`. Don't forget to set `isInFlight = false` when the player is no longer in flight.

Comment: I did not understand where to set the (isInFlight = false)

Comment: I don't know where you would put that without seeing your whole project, but you would put it wherever you make the player stop flying.

Comment: i added in didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) isInFlight = false 
in didEnd(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) isInFlight = true

Now when the character touches only the right wall everything works and when the character touches the left wall in the console writes  «End» and the touch does not work

P.s. I updated the code

Comment: Sounds like it’s printing “End” because you call for that to be printed in your didEnd method. I would probably be using touchesBegan and touchesEnded to set isInFlight instead of didBegin and didEnd, but your project may have different needs.

Comment: I updated the code to show the use of `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`. Not sure if that's what you are confused about.